# How do I set the constructor arguments when deploying using OpenZeppelin CLI?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, constructor

My Token contract compiles fine using solidity 0.5.0:

```
import "/Users/lennard/Desktop/GGToken/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "/Users/lennard/Desktop/GGToken/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "/Users/lennard/Desktop/GGToken/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract GGToken is ERC20Capped, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Burnable {

    constructor (uint256 cap)
        ERC20Detailed("GGToken", "GGT", 18)
        ERC20Capped(cap)
        public {
            _mint(msg.sender, 10000);
    }
}
```

When I deploy this contract in Remix I get the option to set a constructor argument:

[image]

When I try to deploy the same contract using OpenZeppelin CLI's `npx oz create` I don't see this option, and it throws `error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!`

How do I set this constructor argument using OpenZeppelin CLI?

Comment: Try to post it on [OpenZeppelin Community](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/), they are usually a lot more "responsive" than this website.

Comment: If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your contract has a constructor (regular contracts) rather than an initializer (upgradeable contracts) I assume you are deploying a regular contract.

OpenZeppelin CLI supports deploying regular (non-upgradeable) contracts from 2.8.
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/openzeppelin-cli-2-8-release-candidate/2297

OpenZeppelin CLI 2.8 is currently at release candidate.
To install run `npm i @openzeppelin/cli@rc`

We can then deploy a regular contract using the OpenZeppelin CLI and the interactive commands will ask for the constructor parameters:

```
$ npx oz deploy
✓ Compiled contracts with solc 0.5.17 (commit.d19bba13)
? Choose the kind of deployment regular
? Pick a network development
? Pick a contract to deploy Token
? cap: uint256: 1000000000000
✓ Deployed instance of Token
0xe78A0F7E598Cc8b0Bb87894B0F60dD2a88d6a8Ab
```

As an aside, we don't need to specify the full path for imports and can start at @openzeppelin.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract Token is ERC20Capped, ERC20Detailed, ERC20Burnable {

    constructor (uint256 cap)
        ERC20Detailed("Token", "TKN", 18)
        ERC20Capped(cap)
        public {
            _mint(msg.sender, 10000);
    }
}
```